# heroku run only index page angular 4 error

Tags: angular, heroku

[The Heroku deploy my angular appliction without any error , but it did'nt compile my  html code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJCUB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `Content-Type` header for the file that's being returned. Currently, your index page is returning as `Content-Type: application/json`, so your browser is returning the HTML as text.

Change it to `text/html` and your browser will render the page properly.

Currently:

```
$ curl -I -s "https://<your-app>.herokuapp.com/" | grep "^Content-Type: "
Content-Type: application/json
```

After you fix it should show

```
$ curl -I -s "https://<your-app>.herokuapp.com/" | grep "^Content-Type: "
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: // Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

    i have change it but the problem still persist